# Javascript - How to invoke a method inside self invoking function?

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

In the below code

```
(function x() {
var j = function() { alert("234234"); }
return {
    s: j
}
})()

var x1 = new x();
x1.s();
```

How to invoke the method j()? Or before that i should be asking, is there a way to create an instance of the function x() because that is what is happening. Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e5k6bdvn/

Comment: Why do you have it like that to begin with? That pattern does not make sense.

Comment: You code is very odd. You seem to have built something following the module pattern (except you used a named function), and then you invoke the function that should only be self-invoked *again* but as if it was a constructor function (which it definitely isn't designed to be)

Comment: True! you caught that. the whole idea is not to make it a constructor function. but rather am trying to find a way to invoke method j inside it. By the way, self invoking functions cannot be a constructor function??

Comment: It makes no sense to write a self-invoking constructor function. Constructor functions are good for creating multiple instances of an object type. Self-invoking functions are good for creating singletons.

Comment: Allrite, I get the point. My question still remains unanswered. Can self invoking functions be a constructor function? since i am getting error while creating an instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Don't give the self invoking function a name (there is little benefit to it beyond making it easier to find in a stacktrace, which you shouldn't need at that point, and it memory leaks in old IE)
2. Don't call the self invoking function twice
3. Don't treat the self invoking function as if it was a constructor function (by calling it with `new`)
4. Do capture the return value of the self-invoking function

Such:

```js
    var x = (function () {
        var j = function() { alert("234234"); };
        return {
            s: j
        };
    })();
    
    x.s();
```

---

Or, if you want to create multiple objects in the same way:

1. Don't use a self-invoking function
2. Do call `x` as many times as you like

Such:

```js
    function x () {
        var j = function() { alert("234234"); };
        return {
            s: j
        };
    };

    var x1 = x();
    var x2 = x();
    x1.s();
```

---

Or, if you want to create a constructor function:

1. Don't return anything from it
2. Do use the prototype chain

Such:

```js
    function x () {
    };

    x.prototype.s = function () {
        alert("234234");
    }
    
    var x1 = new x();
    var x2 = new x();
    x1.s();
```

Comment: Thanks, 1 question. In my code, I am getting an error while executing var x1 = new x(). Is something wrong with the way i am creating an instance or it is just not possible to treat a self invoking function as a constructor function?

Comment: In your original code there is one variable `x` as it is scoped to the named function expression `x` and isn't accessible outside it. You don't store the function you are trying to call anywhere, so you can't access it. Even if you did store it - it has an explicit return statement and doesn't use `this` so it makes no sense to try to use it as a constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @epascarello, it's hard to say what is the context of your question.

If the meaning of `x` is to return objects more than once, you should not immediately invoke it. Instead you need only to declare it:

```
function x () { return { j: function () { alert("234234") } } }
```

then call it whenever you want, and invoke `j`.

```
var x1 = x();
x1.j();
```

If instead you're planning to use `x` only once, it's nice to invoke it immediately, but you need to consume the call to `j` immediately too.

```
(function () {
    return {
        j: function () {
            alert("234234")
        }
    }
})().j();
```